# How do I get dragon armor pieces?

Tags: pc, dragons-of-atlantis

How do I acquire all four required dragon armor pieces to upgrade `Aerial Combat` to level 1?  I've been told you do it by destroy Anthropus tribes, and I've destroyed hundreds of them from level 1 to level 8 and still haven't gotten any.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get dragon armor pieces you need to attack level 5 and higher Anthropus camps. The drop rate is also random so you'll need to keep attacking to get the pieces. It took me a long time, but the key is the level 5 or higher camps. Lower level camps do not allow you to get the pieces.

For all your other subsequent dragons (water, stone, fire, etc.) you need to attack specific types of wildernesses and you must send a dragon out with these attacks to get the armor pieces.

Water - Level 7+ Lakes

Stone - Level 7+ Hills

Fire - Level 7+ Mountains

Wind - Level 7+ Savannas

There are other special dragons as well, but they require a little more work to get.

You can find all other information related here:  http://dragonsofatlantis.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons

Comment: Waving the level five camp next to my city was the answer, thank you. :D